# Show that $J(S) \subseteq J(T) $ and that T is a topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ and $J:\mathcal{P} (X)\rightarrow \mathcal{P} $ be a function with the following properties :

- $J(X) =X$
- $J(S) \subseteq S$
- $J(S\cap T) =J(S) \cap J(T) $
  fot all $S, T\in \mathcal{P} (X)$.

1. Let $S, T\in \mathcal{P} (X)$. Show that $J(S) \subseteq J(T) $ for $S\subseteq T$.
2. Show that $T=\{S\in \mathcal{P} (X) \mid S=J(S) \} $ is a topology on $X$.

$$$$

To show the first one :

We have that $S\subseteq T$.

Feok the second property of the function we get $J(S) \subseteq S$ and $J(T) \subseteq T$.

So we have to compare $S$ and $J(T) $ to get tge result, don't we?

Comment: Hint: if $S \subseteq T$, then $S \cap T = S$.

Comment: Then we have from the third property that $J(S) =J(S) \cap J(T) $ which must mean that $J(S) \subset J(T) $, right? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great!! As for the second part, we have to show that the set X and the empty set are elements of T, any union of elements of T belongs to T and any finite intersection of elements of T belongs to T, right? @TheoBendit

Comment: Some of these properties are fairly straightforward to show, @mary. Which ones do you do you need help with specifically?

Comment: The union one, to me, looks to be the trickiest one.

Comment: Property 1: we have that J(X) =X and so it is again in T. For the empty set do we use the third property of J, i. E. The intersection of the empty set with a set S is again the emoty set and since the empty set is a subset of each set we get the desired result ? Property 3: it follows from the third property of J, or not? Property 2: could you give me a hint for this one? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, $X \in \tau$ (the topology) is that simple. Closure under intersection does follow immediately from the third property of $J$. To get $X \in \tau$, all you need is $J(\emptyset) \subseteq \emptyset$ from the second property. In terms of the unions, you just need to show $\bigcup_{\alpha} S_\alpha \subseteq J\left(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_\alpha\right)$, where $J(S_\alpha) = S_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$. Use the third property of $J$, with $T$ being the union, and $S$ being some $S_\alpha$.

Comment: What do you mean by T being the union? @TheoBendit

Comment: I mean, $T = \bigcup_{\alpha} S_\alpha$.

Comment: So you mean to consider $\cup_aS_a \cap S_a$? @TheoBendit

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: bonus exercise: finally show that $\operatorname{int}_T(A)=J(A)$ for all $X \subseteq X$.

Comment: I will try that one!! @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: if $S \subseteq T$ then $S \cap T = S$ and so by the last property, $J(S)=J(S\cap T) = J(S) \cap J(T)$ and it follows that $J(S) \subseteq J(T)$ again.

For 2: let $\mathcal{T} = \{A \subseteq X\mid J(A)=A\}$. Checking the axioms:

- $X= J(X)$ so $X \in \mathcal{T}$. Also, $J(\emptyset) \subseteq \emptyset$ so $J(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.
- If $U,V \in \mathcal{T}$ then $J(U)=U, J(V)=V$ so $J(U \cap V)=J(U) \cap J(V) = U \cap V $ so $J(U \cap V)= U \cap V$ And $U \cap V \in \mathcal{T}$, showing that $\mathcal{T}$ is closed under finite intersections.
- Let $U_i, i \in I$ be a family of subsets in $\mathcal{T}$ (so $J(U_i)=U_i$ for all $i$). Let $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$. So for all $i$, $U_i \subseteq U$ and so, using fact 1: $U_i = J(U_i) \subseteq J(U)$, and as this holds for all $i$: $U = \bigcup_i U_i \subseteq J(U) \subseteq U$. So $J(U)=U$ and $U \in \mathcal{T}$ and the topology is closed under all unions.

Comment: At the relation $U = \bigcup_i U_i \subseteq J(U) \subseteq U$ I don't really understand how we get $\bigcup_i U_i \subseteq J(U) $. We have that $ \bigcup\limits_i U_i = \bigcup\limits_i J(U_i)$. Is the last one a subset of $J(U)$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar all $U_i$ are a subset of $J(U)$ by the previous so their union is too.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)